# Enabling FANOTIFY in alpine linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, alpine-linux

I want to enable FANOTIFY in alpine linux VM, I see it's disabled by default [here](https://github.com/alpinelinux/linux-stable-grsec/blob/linux-3.18.y-grsec/fs/notify/fanotify/Kconfig#L5). A few articles suggested I can enable this build kerel, is there any other way to enable this on a running VM, without building kernel?

I tried searching for linux kernel modules which can be enabled on runtime, but couldn't find one.